# Given a list of objects, extract N objects that have a similar size

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have a list of objects in a 2D space, each object, of course, have an XY position an a Width and Height.

I want to extract N objects that have most similar size.

For example:

```
Size Object 1 : 100 (10 W x 10 H)

Size Object 2 : 150

Size Object 3 : 140

Size Object 4 : 160

Size Object 5 : 140
```

In this case, for N = 4, the returning list will be: `Objects: {2,3,4,5}`

My idea is to calculate the average size and get one-by-one the object nearest to the average.
But this approach fail when there are big objects that rise the average.

Any suggestion?

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you want this on C# or Java?

Comment: Geometric mean or mean squares of differences from arithmetic mean?

Comment: I dont need any source, i have choose 2 languages that i can understand pretty well, if someone post a source.

Comment: There is a whole portion of machine learning dedicated to researching this problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis -- You could probably just do simple K-means clustering or expectation-maximation (EM). Without a more detailed specification of *exactly* what answer you want for any input, this is the most specific I can be.

Comment: @TimothyShields I dont need to cluster the object. I need only to take N size-similar objects. This problem is not on the position, but on the size.

Comment: This is probably quite easy to do by sorting the list and just stepping through it, though you'll probably have to be more specific about how **exactly** you want to define similarity.

Comment: @Dukeling the best finding. I dont wanna use a threshold.
But you haved a good idea, sorting the list and stepping through it calculating one by one each object[i]...object[n] total similarity.

Comment: Need more info on this. A lot more info. If all you want to do is compare the total "volume", it's a trivial check. We'll need more info about this problem in order to help.

Comment: @Univers3 Your problem is formulated as something like "(1) Cluster objects based on size (2) Return the objects in the largest cluster"

Comment: An example formulation: "select N objects where the difference in size of the biggest object and the smallest object is minimized". Just telling us to select **similar** objects isn't precise enough. @TimothyShields using the word **cluster** might complicate solution too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step one is to sort the input array by size.  Then, iterate through the array while keeping a running set of the "most similar" elements, however you're defining that.  Let's say that a set of N elements is the "most similar" if it minimizes the difference between the least and greatest element of the set, then your algorithm will look like

```
Deque leastSet = new LinkedList(); // use a Deque instead of a Set because order is important, and presumably your inputArray doesn't contain duplicates anyway; if the input may contain duplicates, then use a LinkedHashSet instead
Deque currentSet = new LinkedList();

// initialize deques with first N elements
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    leastSet.addLast(inputArray[i]);
    currentSet.addLast(inputArray[i]);
}

for(int i = N; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    currentSet.removeFirst();
    currentSet.addLast(inputArray[i]);
    if((currentSet.peekLast() - currentSet.peekFirst()) < (leastSet.peekLast() - leastSet.peekFirst())) {
        leastSet = currentSet.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: *use a Deque instead of a Set because order is important* you could use a `LinkedHashSet` for the job too.

Comment: +1 If the input contains duplicates and a duplicate occurred at the edge of the set of N it would not be included. So you would just need to check the elements on the upper edge of the set to see if they are duplicates of the last element in the set.

Comment: Yes, i think getting the lowest difference of the limit elements of the set is very good!
Whatever, the List dont contains duplicates.

Comment: I have just implemented the solution and works like a charme.
Thank you. And thank you to @Dukeling too.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force would be to create a set of buckets (array of lists) from min val to max val. Start with a delta of 1. Loop through each element and put it into each bucket from val - delta to val + delta. Determine if any bucket has n elements. If not increase the delta by one and repeat.

Another (probably better option). Sort by size. Start with a small maxdelta like 1. Then look at each element (i) and element (i+n). If i & i+n have a delta less than maxdelta this is your set (or at least the start of your set as there might be additional elements). If not increment i. If no set found increment maxdelta and repeat.